# Set controller in directive vs ng-controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a custom directive where I specify the controller like this:

```
module.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',    
    scope: {
      attr1: "@myAttribute1",
      attr2: "@myAttribute2"
    },
    template: '<div>Some content</div>',
    controller: 'MyController'
  }
});
```

However when I do this, a button on the page with the ng-click attribute set does not trigger on touch devices. Everything else works a expected.

Then I tried to outcomment the controller and then the button works.

Then I added the controller to the div with ng-controller and then the button also works.

```
module.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',    
    scope: {
      attr1: "@myAttribute1",
      attr2: "@myAttribute2"
    },
    template: '<div ng-controller="MyController">Some content</div>'
  }
});
```

So basically, what is the difference between the two ways of specifying the controller when the scope is isolated?

(I guess the error with the ng-click is caused by something in MyController, but if I figure out the difference between the two ways to specify the controller, then I might be able to find the cause of the error.)

**Edit:**

The directive is used like this

```
<my-directive my-attribute1="Val1" my-attribute2="Val2"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML code ? Are you sure you correctly set the directive? Because if you specify your directive in the HTML code you have to use `my-directive` notation and not `myDirective`. With some HTML code I could have verified myself immediately.

Comment: You're right, I added HTML code of how I'm using the directive. Everything works fine, except for the ng-click trigger on the button on touch devices.